# regular expression for getting single occourance of a character from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, regular-language

I have some alphanumeric strings. From that I have to find out those strings which satisfy the following condition,

1. There should be only one character in the whole string and that should be 'e'
2. 'e' should not present at the beginning or end of the string it should be present at the middle.

I want to pick strings like `43e4234,435345e5`

I can do the same thing in ruby, but as i have huge number of strings i want to go with regular expression only

Comment: Sounds like a mere `/\A\d+e\d+\z/` should be enough.

Comment: This makes no sense. If there is only one character in the whole string, then `e` must be present at the beginning and the end. If it *isn't* present at the beginning or the end, there must be some *other* character there, and then there are at least *two* characters in the string. Your requirements are contradictory: it is impossible to have a string that consists of only one character yet at the same time consists of more than one character. The examples you posted violate constraint #1, since they contain the characters `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5` in addition to `e`.

Comment: `2,3,4,5` i am treating as digits

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
/\A[^a-z]+e[^a-z]+\z/i
```

It means :

- Beginning of the string
- at least one non-letter
- 'e'
- at least one non-letter
- end of string

Here's an example : 
https://regex101.com/r/H9oza7/1

Use `/^[^a-z]+e[^a-z]+$/im` if you want to match lines inside a string.